# Alamofire problems Xcode 8 GM Ambiguous reference to member request

Tags: alamofire, ambiguous

I updated to xcode 8 GM and this lead me to update my Alamofire package and I have not been able to fix what used to work before, where now I get this error

> "Ambiguous reference to member request"

```
public func executeWebRequest(url: String) -> Request
{
    let defaultHeaders: [String : String] = ["Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8", "Accept": "application/json"]


    let parameters = [
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": ["a", 1],
        "qux": [
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2,
            "z": 3
        ]
    ] as [String : Any]

    let restRequest = Alamofire.request(url,
                                     withMethod: .post,
                                     parameters: parameters,
                                     encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                                     headers:defaultHeaders)
    return restRequest
}
```

This was working with beta6 and now is not. I am not able to find to problem. I tired this in the test case of the Alamofire project its self and I am not getting the error, only in my project which is a framework.

My take is that some how some thing change in the way to set the framework and its causing this. wondering if any one did get the same and with luck did find a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can blame the Swift interpreter for being so uninformative. Change `withMethod:` to `method:`. It changed in a recent commit to Alamofire and I had the same issue!

Comment: Thanks! :) indeed Swift can be so vague at times.